# After updating to version 2.4.4, when I enter the admin panel, I get an error: "An error has happened during application run."

Tags: magento2, error, login, admin-panel

When I try to login to the admin panel, I get the following error: 'An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details.'

After cleaning the cookies, the error disappears and it turns out to go to the admin panel.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Can you please add the logs getting generated in the exception.log file when this error is getting generated? I am using M2.4.4 but I didn't face this issue yet.

Answer (score 0):

Will be hard to debug without getting the error from the logs first. If you see this error again, review `var/log/exception.log` from your Magento project root. This should give you a more detailed explanation of the error.